# Add values stored in a dictionary as a list of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've been searching online for a solution, but everything I've done hasn't been working so far. As the title says, I have a dictionary with a list of values stored in it. I need to add those values together. How would I go about doing that? There are about 1000+ keys and values in the dictionary too, this is just a small example.

```
{'10_Principles_of_Economics': ['13', '13'],'Advanced_ANOVA': ['2', '1', '1', '2'], 'Advanced_Classical_Mechanics': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 'Agile_software_development': ['1', '2']}
```

This is what I tried:

```
def convert_to_dict(matches):
    dictionary = dict()
    [dictionary[t[0]].append(t[1]) if t[0] in (dictionary.keys())
     else dictionary.update({t[0]: [t[1]]}) for t in matches]
    print(dictionary)
    return dictionary


def sum_dictionary(dictionary):
    dd3 = {}
    for key in dictionary:
        dd3[key] = [sum(dictionary[key])]
```

I know there is something wrong here, but I'm not completely sure what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would your expected output look like?

Comment: Like this: {'10_Principles_of_Economics': ['26'],'Advanced_ANOVA': ['6'], 'Advanced_Classical_Mechanics': ['6'], 'Agile_software_development': ['3']} Just adding the values together.

Comment: Either return `dd3` or do the operation inplace.

Comment: What does your current output look like? Is it just erroring out? Also, it looks like you're not converting between strings and integers. Could that be your problem?

Comment: The code in the example gives me: Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. It doesn't add the values together.

Comment: I'm guessing the values are just strings right now. Are you saying I would need to convert the values to integers?

Comment: @Will91099 Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
dd4 = {k:sum([int(v) for v in val]) for k,val in dd3.items()}
```

#### Output:

```
{'10_Principles_of_Economics': 26,
 'Advanced_ANOVA': 6,
 'Advanced_Classical_Mechanics': 6,
 'Agile_software_development': 3}
```

Your final function would look like this:

```
def sum_dictionary(dictionary):
    return {k:sum([int(v) for v in val]) for k,val in dictionary.items()}
```

Please tell me if there's something you don't understand. Be careful to use the same variables in your function definition as the ones inside it.

If you want the sum on a list as strings (as stated in your comment), just change this:

```
 {k:[str(sum([int(v) for v in val]))] for k,val in d.items()}
```

#### Output 2:

```
{'10_Principles_of_Economics': ['26'],
 'Advanced_ANOVA': ['6'],
 'Advanced_Classical_Mechanics': ['6'],
 'Agile_software_development': ['3']}
```

Comment: The output I want is the first one you listed. I'm still having an issue where it's only displaying the separate values. Maybe it's where I'm placing the code. Would you place this: dd4 = {k:sum([int(v) for v in val]) for k,val in dd3.items()}  under the for loop?

Comment: It's not under the loop, it replaces the loop. Here I use list comprehensions and dict comprehensions which are two ways to avoid loops (always avoid them if you can)

Comment: I edited my answer so you can use it as a function. Then you just have to call `sum_dictionary(dd3)`

Answer (score 0):

somethig like this:

```
d = {
    '10_Principles_of_Economics': ['13', '13'],
    'Advanced_ANOVA': ['2', '1', '1', '2'], 
    'Advanced_Classical_Mechanics': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
    'Agile_software_development': ['1', '2']
}
```

**Python 3.x**

```
for key, value in d.items():
    d[key] = [str(sum([int(x) for x in value]))]

print (d)
```

**Python 2.x**

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
```